# Angular routerLink / (click) event does not work properly

Tags: angular, routerlink, clickevent

I found a strange problem with **routerLink** and **(click)** event handler.
In such code where I use **<br/>** tag the second **<a..>** works well but the first one doesn't work.
In case if I change order of **<a..>** tags to opposit - **routerLink** starts to work well but **(click)** doesn't work.

```
<a routerLink="/profile">Profile</a> <br/> 
<a (click)="logout()">LogoutMe</a>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I tried to put **routerLink** into **<div>** without any success

```
<div><a routerLink="/profile">Profile</a></div> 
<a (click)="logout()">LogoutMe</a>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

In such version of code where I replaced **<br/>** with **&nbsp;** both links work well

```
<a routerLink="/profile">Profile</a> &nbsp; 
<a (click)="logout()">LogoutMe</a>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Everything I put inside **<ng-content>** works correctly.

What can be a reason of such a strange issue? I removed all the code which would affect the issue without any success.

(Angular 17.2.0, Visual Studio template for Angular + ASP.NET core template)

Comment: HI could you provide a stackblitz repro of your issue ? Thx

Comment: No, I can't add the repo to stackblitz. I tried to reproduce the simplified version of the app there - everything works well. The code I added to the post is a part of separate module - layout module. Pages which use the layout are it their own module - pages module. Pages module has routes defined, layout module has no any route definition, just set of controls like header-footer-layout-menu etc.

Comment: if you replace the routerLink with a (click) function and log inside two functions: do you receive both events?
if no there is a css issue in your code.

Comment: No, I recieve only event from second element. In the first position neither (click) nor routerLink works properly until I change <br/> by &nbsp;
No any CSS used yet.